# Shortest meeting point of two paths

Tags: language-agnostic, shortest-path, path-finding

[image: Example image]

### Explanation :

In the example picture above there is a green circle following an arbitrary path.

I want the red circle to meet the green circle in the minimum steps possible as demonstrated in the picture.

The circles can move to any of the 8 adjacent cells in one step and black cells can’t be traversed.

The paths are represented as a list of coordinates. In this case, **the green path
is [(0,3),(0,2),(0,1)...(5,0)]**.

To find the shortest meeting point I can iterate though each coordinate in the green path list and use the A* algorithm to find the shortest path from the red circle to that coordinate. If the length of the path returned is equal to the number of steps it takes the green circle to get to that coordinate, then the shortest meeting point path is found.

This is of course, a brute force approach and the java code looks something like this:

```
List<Coord> minMeetingPointPath(Coord redLoc, List<Coord> greenPath) {
    for (int step = 0; step < greenPath.size(); step++) {
        Coord greenLoc = greenPath.get(step);
        List<Coord> redPath = shortestPathAStar(redLoc, greenLoc);
        if (redPath.size() == step)
            return redPath;
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Question

So my question is:

1. Is there a **more efficient way** to solve this problem without using a brute force approach?

Comment: This is actually slightly trickier in general because the best path may include a "wait" step (consider the case where the starting points are adjacent and green moves towards red, if red goes anywhere at all they will meet later than at time=1).

Comment: Plus, in general they may sometimes not even be a solution before green hits the grid's boundary.

Comment: I don' t think that would be a problem in this particular program as they take turns to make a step.

Comment: OK, slightly different in that case, but still interesting: it means that sometimes your goal is to get one step ahead of green and then let it catch you in the next step (but no waiting). Note that A* does not require the target to be a fixed position in space, termination can be any condition, the difficulty is mostly in the heuristic and I'll have to think about that. Chebyshev distance clearly doesn't work, maybe if you halve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 ways you could make it more efficient

1) start with the goal. 
  start with the green ball. Find (and keep track of) the shortest path from the green position to the red node position. This on it's own will not reduce the search but if you limit the depth of the search to the move number (ie move 0 search to depth of 0 move 1 search to a depth of 1 ... move n search to a depth of n) it will reduce the time you spend searching since you will only be searching to the relevant depth, anything past that point is of no value and does not need to be checked.

2) Don't search at all if you don't need to. Give your search a seance of depth, you already have each node with an x,y positions of the start and finish so before you do your A* search check the move number and the straight line distance 
For example: the shortest distance between 0,5 (green current position) and 0,0 (red start position) is 5 so if the green object is on move is move 4 or less you know there is no way to get there even if there is nothing blocking the way. however if it is move 5 or more you know there might a way to get to that location in time so it is worth searching to see how long the path actually takes.

Comment: Very usefull answer. Thank you.